Implementing a Half-bridge (half h bridge) from scratch in tinkercad, facing simulation problem! (more details in post) (12V~24V)



I am learning about motor controllers and I would like to learn them in depth and in as much detail as possible. I am trying to build my own H-bridge from only MOSFETs and other small circuit components like resistors and diodes (zeners, etc...) in order to control a DC motor.
I found this useful resource: https://www.gammon.com.au/motors which explains high-side and low-side control in great detail.
I have been able to implement primitive H-bridges using only 4 MOSFETs for my circuit components. This was implemented in Tinkercad and the supply voltage was 5V.
When I moved to higher supply voltages I have hit a wall. I would really really like to control motors at high voltages say 24V and above and I know most MOSFETs can only work optimally at VGS of +/- 10V or some even push to 20 V max. I am going to do this using zener diodes and extra NPN transistors for the high-side (to clamp the voltage to safe levels) and logic level N-MOSFETs for the low-side (logic-level can be directly controlled by MCU/Arduino).
The problem is when I try to make a simple half bridge in tinkercad (one N-MOSFET, and one P-MOSFET whose gate is controlled using a "pull-up" circuit with an NPN as shown in the black-white circuit diagram), I get the result shown in the simulation screenshot. That is: the motor RPM's stays 0, the current is somehow 5 A while the voltage is 0V. This is unusual/something is not working at all as intended. Note that the voltage here is 12 V. The current does not matter as it adjusts based on the loads, I keep it at 5 A but changing both voltage and current of supply has zero effect.
I would like to mention that this problem has persisted a few days and I found no solution for this, specifically regarding a Tinkercad simulation of a half-bridge like mine.
I tried to remove the low side circuit and directly grounded the motor's negative terminal. This works well as intended for high side control, but the moment I try to control the negative terminal/black wire of motor with the NMOS it just does not work and produces the result in the screenshot.
I deleted this project and redone it a few times but nothing worked.
I also grounded the Arduino, I mistake I commit often is that I forget to do that but I repeated this so many times now I think I got rid of the basic "Gotchas!"
I would be immensely grateful for any help regarding this as I want to move on to real life projects with confidence.
I don't want to misunderstand a very fundamental thing about electricity this far in!!
Note: NMOSFET and PMOSFET pinout = Gate - Drain - Source (left hand-side to right hand-side ->) exact order as you are looking at screenshot.
NPN pinout as you are facing screenshot (LHS to RHS): Emitter - Base - Collector.
Hidden wires: There is power supply to the PMOSFET source that's obstructed by the PMOS. The motor's red wire goes to the rail that has the drain on it. Finally the emitter is grounded, it is somewhat visible.
The NMOS source is grounded and the black wire of motor is connected to rail where the drain is.
NPN - Base pin to pin 8 of arduino. (Controls PMOS gate voltage).
NMOSFET - Gate pin to pin 9 of arduino.
The code is extremely basic:
// C++ code
//
void setup()
{
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
}

If you need more information please reach out. I would appreciate any amount of help I mean it. I don't want to conclude Tinkercad is bugged but maybe it is. If some professional can confirm absolutely what I am doing is physically plausible and actually works/should work and that I have no major errors then perhaps Tinkercad is wrong. I want to test this in real life but at the moment I really cannot so I apologize. Again would really appreciate someone saving me from this long and torturous endeavor. I cannot count how many times I repeated this, maybe I am misunderstanding a very important aspect of electricity?? Or perhaps Tinkercad is not suitable for this?
Thanks a lot, I hope someone helps!!
Edit: made and added circuit diagram above!

"I don't want to conclude Tinkercad is bugged" The problem, as you may have noticed in the answer to the previous question, is that it is very hard to parse all the relevant information presented textually and with a wiring diagram. It may be useful to provide documentation to friendly tutorials, but it is much easier and less error prone to follow schematics. Please, kindly edit you question to provide the same information in a more inviting way to receive good feedback.

Hi I really appreciate your response! I wanted to include the autogenerated schematic from tinkercad but it is not so elegant and not easy to read. The schematic I implemented is the same as the one in the image I pasted. Does that suffice? If I were to draw one it would probably be exactly the same. For making the content seem more inviting I would appreciate any advice you give me! Thanks again I appreciate the interaction

The schematic is similar but it doesn't have the same components and control inputs.

Oh right my bad it is missing the rest, the low side control. I will be on it then thanks for pointing it out!

@devnull I now edited my question. I used Fritzing to draw the circuit diagram (added it, third image above). Also, ignore the 9V it is supposed to be 12V sorry! Please let me know if this alright, would really appreciate it. Thanks!

What do you expect the half-bridge will bring which the standard low side drive can't?

It is hard to understand what you are trying to achieve by mixing the two circuits. The high side driver in your post is correct as is this other one, at the low side, from the same link you mentioned:

In your own schematic it seems you are trying to mix both designs for some unclear reason. Either one will work fine with a single GPIO from the arduino but both with the motor in series do not form a half bridge, as expected.

I would really really like to control motors at high voltages say 24V and above

Again, the site you mentioned has a solution for this. The Zener keeps the Vgs at safe levels and both the PMOS the BJT should be able to withstand the higher voltage when not conducting:


perhaps Tinkercad is not suitable for this?

It certainly is not a substitute for learning about the components and how they work (it just shows how to connect things). Wiring diagrams are confusing and error prone. Additionally, not learning schematics will make it more difficult to search the technical sites and literature.

just made a half bridge because as a first step this is easier to debug

Now it is clear, you made a half H-bridge for debugging. This is a half bridge (source) I was thinking about:

Sure, each half of the h-bridge should work, and it was mentioned that you built them completely with 4 MOSFETs. Check you connections, pinout, if the GPIO is not damaged due to accidental connection to 12 V or 24 V etc.

I'm assuming my schematic is correct

You are relying on the GPIO entirely (check the low side driver above). The gate will be floating for a very short time before the GPIO is configured as output. Additionally, the NMOS should be fully on with the voltage provided by the microcontroller.
Mixing everything to handle: higher voltage for the motor, low side switching and a NMOS which needs higher gate voltage to fully turn on? Maybe this is a starting point (inverted activation at the GPIO):


I really appreciate your reply thanks for taking the time! The reason I connected the motor on series to both circuits is because I want to build an h bridge. If you think about it when an h bridge is conducting only a half bridge let's current through. So basically the motor will be in series. I just made a half bridge because as a first step this is easier to debug. I am not aware of any issue with connecting the motor in series, is there a reason this is not supposed to work? I'm assuming my schematic is correct??

Thanks for a answering my further questions I really appreciate it!

Alright I think tinkercad has a problem I ended up moving to Fastlas: https://www.falstad.com/circuit/
Since it is more professional and all.
